# What does "apply to" mean here?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context, semantics

Taylor Swift:She won by being a female applying to the kind of female males want us to be in the horrendous 1950s world.

Context: I can’t believe she gets to be the first female senator in Tennessee.And she’s Trump in a wig.She represents no female interest.She won by being a female applying to the kind of female males want us to be in the horrendous 1950s world.

Comment: It’s a situation that really bothers me from time to time where no sense that is given by any dictionary I could possibly find seems to applies.Could you guys just use the word as the dictionary says?

Comment: I don't know who "you guys" refers to, but only Taylor Swift is responsible for Taylor Swift's use of English. Was this a spoken interview? (Speaking tends to be less "normal")

Comment: @Andrew Leach  Yeah, it’s from an interview. Could "applying to" mean something like "belonging to" here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quote appears is in several publications.

> She won by being a female applying to the kind of female males want us to be in a horrendous 1950s world.

It may be that "applying" is meant to be "appealing". The quote means that Taylor Swift believes the senator in question gained support from male voters by presenting herself as the kind of 1950's female which would appeal to them, and who is not on the side of women's or minority rights at all.

Comment: I think if it was meant to be "appealing" then the object of it should be the males from whom she wanted to gain support.Could "applying to" mean something like "belonging to" here?

Comment: That was my interpretation: appealing to 20th-century males who would like the 1950's female model.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Taylor made a mistake because according to the Daily Mail, it has been editorially corrected as "by being a female representing..."